# Map of Key with List Object print empty Object in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

Trying to Create the Map in JavaScript for key as program and List of Object. Below is the Json Object

```
JSONPObject.program = [
    {
     
        "Id": "a0l5e000002mFg8AAE",
        "Program__c": "a0I5e000000emtDEAQ",
        "Name": "PL-000"
    },
    { 
        "Id": "a0l5e000002mFg9AAE",
        "Program__c": "a0I5e000000emtDEAQ",
        "Name": "PL-001"
    }    
]
```

```
 const objprogramLocations = JSON.parse(JSONPObject.program);
                    objprogramLocations.forEach(datainfo => {
                        if (!this.program[datainfo.Program__c]) {
                            this.program[datainfo.Program__c] = [];
                        }
                       alert(datainfo.Program__c + datainfo);
                        this.program[datainfo.Program__c].push(datainfo);
                    });

console.log("program--> " + JSON.stringify(this.program));
```

`this.program` is printing the empty object . but i can print the value inside forEach, Can anyone help me what i am missing here

Answer (score 1):

If you don't `@track` a variable, then a render cycle won't be triggered for the property unless you assign a new object to the variable. So, you have two choices; either add [`@track`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_decorators) to your variable, or use an assignment that replaces the variable. So, your options are:

```
@track program;
```

Or:

```
this.program = [...this.program];
```

The latter, the spread operator, copies an iterable to an array. By copying the variable to itself, this basically "does nothing" but will trigger a render cycle.